# Is there any way to periodically cut off/ground (to 0 V) an input signal without using a clock signal?

Tags: digital-logic, signal, clock

I'm trying to periodically (it doesn't have to be accurate/precise or be in the same intervals every time) cut off/ground (make it 0 V) an input signal in a digital logic circuit without using a clock, but I'm running into some trouble.

I tried charging a capacitor to trigger transistors to achieve this, but unfortunately, it only works for certain types of input signals.

Due to my circumstances, I can't use pre-made ICs or chips (or anything other than the most fundamental circuit components). I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this or if it is just unfeasible.

Comment: make a rotary switch from an old motor and some misc hardware

Comment: Hire some unemployed and let him do it. :-D -- Just kidding, welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing some more context. What are your requirements, concerning timing for example. A simplified schematic would also help us help you. -- Since the solution will periodically act, this is a "clock". What do you mean by "_without using a clock_"? -- Did you consider an [astable multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Astable), built from discrete transistors plus passive components?